# How to update array with same key in Session Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to store pages visited history in Session-storage.
Session storage is working how I want.

**Problem:** 
When I visit a 1st, 2nd, 3rd, & 4th page and then visit the 2nd page and 3rd page again, it does not update the array again with the 2nd and 3rd page.

Not appending data in array 2nd and 3rd page, these already exist but I visit  these pages again then it should be added in the array.

I want to store every page visited in history in the array.

```
if (window.sessionStorage) {
    var currentTite = document.title;
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    sessionStorage.setItem(currentTite, currentURL);
    //var storedData = sessionStorage.getItem(currentTite);

    for (i = 0; i <= sessionStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        key = sessionStorage.key(i);
        console.log(key);
        val = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sessionStorage` object is not an array. It is an instance of the native `Storage` constructor which persists data on page navigation. And you can have only one value for each key. Your best bet will be to namespace the history in the session under a `history` key and store a JSON array under that key.

Here is an example:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function recordInHistory() {
  var current = sessionStorage.getItem('history');
  if (!current) { // check if an item is already registered
    current = []; // if not, we initiate an empty array
  } else {
    current = JSON.parse(current); // else parse whatever is in
  }
  current.push({
    title: document.title,
    url: window.location.href
  }); // add the item
  sessionStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify(current)); // replace
});
```

To retrieve the history, of-course `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('history'))` will work.

Comment: how can i get all the detail simply in console ?

Comment: @PuzzledBoy just use `console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('history'));`.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy There is nothing wrong with replacing `'history'` with the `currentTite` variable from your question. I would do that if your javascript code is loaded from an external file and used in multiple pages.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to process the data afterwards. Anyway, as `sessionStorage` is a key-value storage, you can't hold different values with the same keys and you can't have duplicate key-value pairs in the storage.

As an option, you can store an array of user's history, represented by objects (`{ title: document.title, url: window.location.href }`). The code will look something like this:

```
var UserHistory = {
   key: 'userHistory',
   push: function() {
      var cur = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(UserHistory.key)) || [];
      cur.push({ title: document.title, url: window.location.href });
      sessionStorage.setItem(UserHistory.key, JSON.stringify(cur));
   },
   get: function() {
      return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(UserHistory.key));
   }
}
UserHistory.get(); // null
UserHistory.push();
UserHistory.get(); // [ Object ]
```

Comment: how can i get all the detail simply in console ?

Comment: @PuzzledBoy there is a `get` method that returns the whole array of data. You then iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of `setItem` is a key, you can append a random number or Date.now() or a counter++ value to make it unique.

```
if (window.sessionStorage) {
    var currentTite = document.title;
    var currentURL = window.location.href;
    sessionStorage.setItem(currentTite + ':' + Date.now().toString(), currentURL);

    for (i = 0; i <= sessionStorage.length - 1; i++) {
        key = sessionStorage.key(i);
        console.log(key);
        val = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: Including `Date.now()` in the sessionStorage key is **not a good idea**. Every time the user reloads the page, you're creating another set of data. How do you determine which set to load, and which set to delete?

Comment: @Mottie you are right,  but isnt that the goal of the question? maybe an increment number is more appropriate.

Comment: Ah, yes, I guess you are right. I don't know why [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) isn't being used.